# Display dropdown menu in the exact right side of textbox in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have an accordion where it has a flex-row textbox and it has icons on its right.
I need to add the menu positioned as shown in the image below

[image]

My code is here

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .accordion {
      margin: 30px;
    }
    
    .accordion-button.collapsed {
      border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid
    }
    
    .accordion-body {
      border-left: #673ab744 1px solid;
      border-bottom: #673ab744 1px solid;
      border-right: #673ab744 1px solid
    }
    
    .accordion-button {
      display: inline!important
    }
    
    .flx-row {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0">

  <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
      
        <div class="flx-row">          
          <div>
            <input type="textbox" value="Accordion Item #1">
          </div>
          <div>
          

        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> More </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end" style="">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Export</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Duplicate</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item tdelete" href="#">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>

  <br><span>Desc goes here</span><br><span>Desc goes here</span>

  </button>
  </h2>
  <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
    <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the first item's accordion body.</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
          Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the second item's accordion body. Let's imagine this being filled with some actual content.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="as-console-wrapper">
    <div class="as-console"></div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".wdelete").off().on('click', function(event) {
      if (confirm(`Are you sure to delete the workflow ${$(this).prev().parent().prev().val()}?`) == true) {
        $(this).closest('.accordion-item').remove();
      }
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
  </script>

  <div class="as-console-wrapper">
    <div class="as-console"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="as-console-wrapper">
    <div class="as-console"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can't use `<button>` inside `<button>`. It is invalid and is not acceptable by browsers. I have checked in Firefox inspector and see that `<button>` for dropdown has been moved to outside or aside with button for accordion.

Comment: Your CSS destroy accordion up/down icon and `flex`. If you want that then it will be OK but if not then remove your `display:` in your custom CSS.

Comment: Could you post this ans by removing display?

Comment: This is newly created demo 1. https://jsfiddle.net/oaghjdwt/ It contains both button together, keep up/down icon but border effect is not good. This is another version. https://jsfiddle.net/oaghjdwt/1/ Dropdown is child of accordion button, keep up/down icon, border effect is good but click on dropdown also toggle accordion button. I did not post as answer because both are not good as I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking accordion like this

[image]

here's full code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .card-header-custom{
      display: flex;
      justify-content:space-between;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container mt-3">
  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header card-header-custom">
        <a class="btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
          Accordion Item #1
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
            More
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Export</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Duplicate</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item tdelete" href="#">Delete</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the first item's accordion body.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a class="collapsed btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the first item's accordion body.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a class="collapsed btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree">
          Accordion Item #3
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the first item's accordion body.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```